# Can both the overlapping genes (in opposite strands) produce proteins?

Tags: molecular-genetics, genomics

I have recognized that both the forward and reverse transcripts from a genomic location code for protein products. Both do occur/express in the tissue of interest. In order to eliminate by chance probability, I have screened my entire list of genes and there are 6 different examples. I would appreciate if anyone having the knowledge about such exceptions could guide me further.

Is this phenomena of protein being coded from both directions (of a given genomic location) possible? Are there any known examples?

Comment: Maybe this can help you? It is about what regulates the directionality of a gene and they seem to include 9% of the genes are translated in both directions. Although it is hard to say without knowing about the organism you are talking about (seems to be eukaryotic, since you mentioned splicing).  http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S1097276514010077

Comment: Many thanks, I have read this paper and its really helpful

Answer (score 6, accepted):

While overlapping antisense RNAs are quite well known, there are very few examples in which both the RNAs from the pair can code for proteins. However, it is not impossible. I can cite one validated example: RU2S ([DCDC2](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/?term=51473)) and RU2AS ([KAAG1](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/gene/?term=353219)) pair.

While RU2S is constitutively and ubiquitously expressed, RU2AS is specifically expressed in kidney, bladder, liver, and testis. It is also expressed in certain tumours ([Peltz and Dougherty, 1999](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2195709)).

[image]

---

<sup>Peltz SW, Dougherty JP. [Antisense Translates into Sense](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2195709). *The Journal of Experimental Medicine.* 1999;190(12):1729-1732.</sup>